# RGBA support in Aptana3 "preview browser"

Tags: css, aptana3, rgba

Does Aptana3 support RGBA colors?

I'm trying to use the alpha value to set transparency for various elements of my page and, while the saved results display correctly in Firefox, Aptana's integrated "preview" doesn't change background when using rgba(x,x,x,x).

I've already tried setting the Browser in Preferences/General/Web Browser.

Thanks in advance!